# Xamarin Forms AndroidMainfest

Tags: xamarin.forms, android-manifest

This is my mainfest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.companyname.Notification">
      <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="27" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
      <uses-permission android:name="${com.companyname.Notification}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
      <permission android:name="${com.companyname.Notification}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
      <application android:label="Notification.Android" android:name="android.app.Application" android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/icon" android:debuggable="true">
        <receiver android:name="com.onesignal.GcmBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
          <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="${com.companyname.Notification}" />
          </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" android:icon="@mipmap/icon" android:label="Notification" android:theme="@style/MainTheme" android:name="md542ccf1b76a5e02a89cf2bd3ef3e134e4.MainActivity">
          <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
          </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name="md5dcb6eccdc824e0677ffae8ccdde42930.KeepAliveService" />
        <receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:name="md51558244f76c53b6aeda52c8a337f2c37.PowerSaveModeBroadcastReceiver" />
        <provider android:name="mono.MonoRuntimeProvider" android:exported="false" android:initOrder="2147483647" android:authorities="com.companyname.Notification.mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.__mono_init__" />
        <!--suppress ExportedReceiver-->
        <receiver android:name="mono.android.Seppuku">
          <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="mono.android.intent.action.SEPPUKU" />
            <category android:name="mono.android.intent.category.SEPPUKU.com.companyname.Notification" />
          </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.onesignal.NotificationOpenedReceiver" />
        <service android:name="com.onesignal.GcmIntentService" />
        <service android:name="com.onesignal.GcmIntentJobService" android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />
        <service android:name="com.onesignal.RestoreJobService" android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />
        <service android:name="com.onesignal.RestoreKickoffJobService" android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />
        <service android:name="com.onesignal.SyncService" android:stopWithTask="true" />
        <service android:name="com.onesignal.SyncJobService" android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />
        <activity android:name="com.onesignal.PermissionsActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
        <service android:name="com.onesignal.NotificationRestoreService" />
        <receiver android:name="com.onesignal.BootUpReceiver">
          <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
          </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.onesignal.UpgradeReceiver">
          <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
          </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" android:exported="false" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
      </application>
      <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
      <uses-permission android:name="com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.READ" />
      <uses-permission android:name="com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.WRITE" />
      <uses-permission android:name="com.htc.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS" />
      <uses-permission android:name="com.htc.launcher.permission.UPDATE_SHORTCUT" />
      <uses-permission android:name="com.sonyericsson.home.permission.BROADCAST_BADGE" />
      <uses-permission android:name="com.sonymobile.home.permission.PROVIDER_INSERT_BADGE" />
      <uses-permission android:name="com.anddoes.launcher.permission.UPDATE_COUNT" />
      <uses-permission android:name="com.majeur.launcher.permission.UPDATE_BADGE" />
      <uses-permission android:name="com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.CHANGE_BADGE" />
      <uses-permission android:name="com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS" />
      <uses-permission android:name="com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_APP_BADGE" />
      <uses-permission android:name="com.oppo.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS" />
      <uses-permission android:name="com.oppo.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
      <uses-permission android:name="me.everything.badger.permission.BADGE_COUNT_READ" />
      <uses-permission android:name="me.everything.badger.permission.BADGE_COUNT_WRITE" />
    </manifest>
```

I keep getting these errors and I don't know what is wrong!!

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Tag  attribute name has invalid character '$'.    Notification.Android    C:\Users\moham\source\repos\Notification\Notification\Notification.Android\obj\Debug\81\android\manifest\AndroidManifest.xml    14
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Tag  attribute name has invalid character '$'.  Notification.Android    C:\Users\moham\source\repos\Notification\Notification\Notification.Android\obj\Debug\81\android\manifest\AndroidManifest.xml    9
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Could not copy the file "obj\x86\Debug\MainPage.xbf" because it was not found.  AppXamarin.UWP

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be configuring OneSignal push notifications but you haven't changed the `android:name="${com.companyname.Notification}"` where the name of it should actually be your apps package name which is this `com.companyname.Notification` in your case

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm doing and if u check I'm adding my package name exactly the way it is. I expected when I delete the '$' and braces the error will be gone. But every time I run my project the '$' and the braces are added to the name!! and the error is popped